# Trying to sync my google calender with my ubuntu desktop using conky and gcalcli but I am getting an error

Tags: 12.04, conky, google-calendar

Following this [guide](http://ubuntuguide.net/display-google-calendar-on-ubuntu-desktop-using-conky) on conky and  gcalcli, I was trying to sync my google calender with my ubuntu desktop. After I do everything and try to run conky, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gcalcli", line 1524, in <module>
    BowChickaWowWow()
  File "/usr/bin/gcalcli", line 1292, in BowChickaWowWow
    cfg = LoadConfig(configFile)
  File "/usr/bin/gcalcli", line 1174, in LoadConfig
    config.read(os.path.expanduser(configFile))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 305, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 512, in _read
    raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
ConfigParser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
file: /home/timur/.gcalclirc, line: 1
'user: "myusername"\n'
```

Note: my text file does actually contain my username.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

I use gcalcli almost everyday.  It is a great program, but in order to display my Google calendar in Conky I use Kaivalagi's Conky Google Calendar Python Script.

See the thread at: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=837385

The script uses conky keyring to securely transmit your credentials .
All of the documentation is very clear and easy to follow with the possible exception of the keyring.

To setup the keyring in a terminal type:
conkyKeyring -u gmail_address -p gmail_password

Here is a screenshot of my calendar in conky via this script:

[image]